# What UML diagram should I use to model main internal structures?

Tags: uml

I am developing a software and need to model it's main internal structures(To figure out what's going on and in the future development) . But I don't know what UML diagram would be better to use. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by what uml should I use,  from what I know there is only one UML , there are other types of diagram like flowchart...

Comment: a Class diagram would help you for modelling your software structure.

Comment: @meda Do you see "Diagram" after "UML"?

Comment: If an answer is helpful for you, please upvote it and / or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Static diagrams will help you, especially a component diagram (because it offers a higher abstraction) and possibly a deployment diagram.